# How to manipulate the position absolute in a div

Tags: css

Please help me with this code.. this is just a sample layout.. 
I want the text to overlay the div.. so it looks like the div will be the background of the text

```
<div>Krishnais so beautiful</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

**css**

```
.box{
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `Position: absolute;` + `top` and `left`

```
.box{
    top:0px;           #delete
    left:0px;          #delete
    position:absolute; #delete
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPRbe/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your text positionned (absolute or relative), with a z-index :

```
.text{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

In order to manipulate Z axis, you can use z-index property. But you can manipulate this property only for positionned elements.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YzfCn/)**

Comment: thanks a lot I'm sorry for some.. who misunderstand my question